# How to resolve runtime dependency issues in Java

Tags: java, maven, classpath

As part of my work, I have to do the following task. I have to write some java code (standalone java class) and execute it in a different environment. So the environment where the code is compiled and run are different. The java class that I am supposed to run has a lot of dependencies on 3rd party jars. So I have created a eclipse maven project, added the dependencies in POM and the code is compiled successfully. The problem comes when I have to actually run the code. I am getting a lot of classnotfound exceptions, which I am resolving by downloading the appropriate jars and putting them in the classpath in the environment. But this is proving to be a very cumbersome process. Is there any way to get eclipse maven to download both the compile time and runtime dependencies at some location so that I can transfer all the jars in the classpath where I am actually running my code.

Comment: Basically an automated way to get all the runtime dependencies in one shot so that I can place all these jars in the classpath and execute my java code

Comment: `which I am resolving by downloading the appropriate jars ` this sounds like you are doing something wrong...add the needed dependencies to your pom file... if you like to make an executable jar which contains all dependencies you should take a look at the maven-shade-plugin....

Comment: But looks like the pom file is only downloading the compile time dependencies needed for the code to compile, but not the runtime dependencies.

Comment: How can I know ? Where is the example which shows the issue ? Which JDK, Maven version etc. do yo use?

Comment: A small quote from the docs: `runtime` means: `This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. Maven includes a dependency with this scope in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.`

Comment: @user496934 this sounds like a  _packaging_ problem: you want to bundle your built code and dependencies into some kind of package that you can deploy to another environment to run. Have a look at the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

Comment: @khmarbaise...you are right, eclipse maven was downloading ALL the required jars. Now when I put ALL the downloaded jars in the new environment classpath, code is running successfully. Now I will explore the two plugins mentioned , thanks